# Como ativar o IIS no windows 10?

Tags: iis, windows-10

Estou tentando instalar o ***IIS*** no windows 10, a instalação não concluí e não mostra nenhum erro. 
Alguém já passou por isso? [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual versão do IIS você está utilizado?

Comment: É Windows 10 home ou pro?

Comment: É o IIS 6 que vem com o windows 10 Home

Comment: @Lorena já tentou atualizar seu windows?

Comment: @Marconi Atualizei e continua com o mesmo problema.

Comment: IIS no windows 10 home vai instalar porém não vai aparecer em ferramentas administrativas para você adicionar e configurar seu site.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Você pode seguir o passos:

Pressione a combinação de teclas `Windows + R` para abrir uma caixa de execução e, em seguida, digite **appwiz.cpl** e pressione enter.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vá em ***Ativar ou desativiar recursos do Windows***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Marque a caixa ***Serviços de Informações da Internet***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Ficará um tempo nessa tela:***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pronto a sua instalação está concluída!

Comment: Fiz exatamente isso, chega no final e diz que o windows não pode completar as atualizações.

Comment: @Lorena tenta atualizar seu windows primeiro!

Comment: está atualizado.

Comment: Reinicia e tenta denovo, estranho não está dando certo! Você está tentando no pc pessoal?

Comment: Sim, estou desde ontem tentando fazer isso é muito estranho.

Comment: tem uma atualização pendente, mas eu faço e da erro.

Atualização do Windows 10 Version 1607 para sistemas baseados em x64 (KB3176936) - Erro 0x80070bc9

Comment: @Lorena achei um tutorial [aqui](https://answers.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/windows-10-n%C3%A3o-baixa-a-atualiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o/0dc5a4c2-9508-4e6b-9ebf-2b5ae6977eca) com o possivel erro da atualização! Tem uma explicação de como resolver.

Comment: resolvi o problema da atualização, mas o IIS ainda não termina a instalação.

Answer (score 5):

O Windows 10 desde a versão Home já possui disponibilidade para IIS.

---

Se precisar instalar lembre que para o **Windows 10** você deve instalar o **IIS10**.

- Download: https://www.microsoft.com/pt-BR/download/details.aspx?id=48264

---

Verifique se o recurso está ativado no seu Windows:

- Clique no botão **Iniciar**
- Pesquise por: **Ativar recursos ou desativar recursos do Windows**
- Selecione a opção: **Serviços de Informações da Internet**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

> Versões mais antigas como Windows 7 Home Basic podem não
>   conter o IIS disponível.

Comment: Eu fiz exatamente isso e no final diz que o windows não pode concluir.

Comment: Lorena, você está como administradora da máquina?

Comment: Sim, estou como administradora.

Comment: Veja se nos eventos do windows não tenha alguma informação sobre o erro que possa estar dando.

Comment: Sua internet tem alguma restrição de acesso?

Comment: Sim @PabloVargas, pode ser isso?

Comment: Pode sim, pois alguns recursos podem ser necessário ser feito o download dos servidores da Microsoft.

Comment: Vou trocar e tentar.. valeu!!

Answer (score 2):

Eu tive uma experiência pessoal similar.

Em uma máquina Windows 10 recém-inicializada e com algumas ferramentas instaladas (antivirus entre uma delas) a instalação do IIS nunca chegava ao fim.

A causa era ligada a conflitos entre o serviço [TrustedInstaller](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/trustedinstaller-exe-windows-7) e a ferramenta de segurança.

Ao desabilitar todos os aspectos de segurança (Firewall e antivirus) a instalação do IIS conseguiu prosseguir até o fim.

Comment: desativei tudo aqui e continua o mesmo problema :/