# Problemas ao habilitar ASP e ASP.NET no IIS

Tags: asp

Bom dia!

Estou tentando habilitar ASP e ASP.NET no IIS e não estou conseguindo.

Eu marco as opções abaixo:
[image]

E a mensagem que aparece é que foi concluído, pedindo para reiniciar. 
[image]

Só que quando reinicio a máquina, aparece tudo desmarcado de novo.

Já atualizei o Windows, já tentei instalar o ISS 10 Express. Mas nada dá certo. Meu Windows é o Windows 10 Home.

Alguém sabe o que pode estar acontecendo??

Obrigada!

Comment: Oi Carla tudo bem? Dá uma olhada nessa pergunta talvez te ajude: [ https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/185603/como-ativar-o-iis-no-windows-10 ]

Comment: Já tinha visto essa pergunta aqui. Mas meu problema é diferente pois o Windows conclui a instalação normalmente mas quando reinicio está tudo desmarcado novamente. Como se eu não tivesse feito a atualização.